# What is "Uma Thurman" in the Fall Out Boy song?

Tags: meaning, song-title

What is *Uma Thurman*? What does that phrase mean in the Fall Out Boy [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hipFGoni6Js)? Is Uma Thurman a person? Is it a style of dancing?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questioner could answer the question instantly with a simple Google search. According to our guidelines, we do not accept questions where it appears that the questioner has done no work of their own to try to find an answer.

Comment: @WheatWilliams - I don't disagree with you that a Google search could reveal the answer to this question. 

But could you provide a link to the guideline where it says this is an unacceptable type of question? I can only find that it's a good practice to do research, not that it is a requirement. Prior research can make a question a "good" one. http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Should the "on topic" guidelines be revised to say the asker must Google first? http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Also, see this meta Q & A. The accepted answer says simple questions should be allowed. http://meta.musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/133/answering-simple-questions

Answer (score 5):

Uma Thurman is an [actress](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0000235/?ref_=nv_sr_1). She was in the film Pulp Fiction.

[Google](https://www.google.com) is your friend.